# Why am I getting run-time error

Tags: c, operating-system, pthreads, codeblocks

Hello I am using Code::Blocks in Windows XP.
When I am running this program I am getting a run time error as `"drawing operation was attempted when there was no current window".`
I would like to know why it is happening so.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
void *print_message_function( void *ptr );

main()
{
   pthread_t thread1, thread2;
   char *message1 = "Thread 1";
   char *message2 = "Thread 2";
   int  iret1, iret2;

   iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message1);
   iret2 = pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message2);

   pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
   pthread_join( thread2, NULL);

   printf("Thread 1 returns: %d\n",iret1);
   printf("Thread 2 returns: %d\n",iret2);

   exit(0);
}

void *print_message_function( void *ptr )
{
   char *message;
   char hello;
   for(;;)
   {
        message = (char *) ptr;
        printf("%s \n", message);
        Sleep(1000);
      //  break;


         fflush(stdin);   
/*drawing operation was attempted when there was no current window*/
//The happens from next line onwords
           if(kbhit())
           {
               hello = getchar();
               printf("The interrupt %d", hello);
           }
       }

    }
```

Comment: `kbhit()` is deprecated, use `_kbhit()` instead.

Comment: @Alexander Bakulin: Thanks A Lot for solving the problem. But just wanted to know why `_knhit()` why not `kbhit()`?

Comment: Good chance to undelete my answer :) `_kbhit()` is said (by MSDN) to be the replacement for deprecated `kbhit()`. I don't know the exact reason behind this decision. See my answer for link to documentation.

Comment: @Alexander Bakulin: Where is the link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kbhit()` is [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235390%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), use `_kbhit()` instead. Perhaps it was the reason.

Answer (score 4):

Your program has an **Undefined Behavior**.
Calling `fflush()` on `stdin` is not allowed and is an Undefined Behavior. It is only allowed to be called on standard output stream `stdout`.
This may or may not be the direct reason of the behavior you are observing, but since it is an Undefined Behavior you never know...

**C99 Standard 7.19.5.2/2:**

> If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent operation was not input, the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is undefined

Comment: I debuged and found it is not because of `fflush()`, its because of `kbhit()`

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak: Good for you :).However, it is still an Invalid program.Just because it works doesn't make it any more valid than it is now.